# What methods are there for posting the current buffer to website

Tags: http

Curious if there is anything to do this currently, basically i want to specify the parameters and post the current buffer as one of the parameters to an external website so i can skip the copy and past step.

Are there any packages or what kind of lisp would i need to achieve this ?

Comment: A buffer is just a fancy string object.You can retrieve its contents in string form with `(buffer-string)`. The hard part here is giving a useful answer to the "external website" part, so I'll leave that to someone else.

Comment: Can you specify what you exactly mean by "an external website?"

Comment: sure, anything really so for example a pastebin site would be quite a simple example or any page that has a text area field really, so you could do a post with some params one of the params being the current buffer.